# How can I convert my pfx-file to a byte[] for use in API-Management?

Tags: arrays, keystore, azure-api-management, client-certificates

**Problem:**
Sending a request from Azure-API-Management to a SOAP-webservice using client certificate authentication, results in a 401-response, whereas I would like to get a 200-response.

**Cause:** When I use the same keystore (pfx) in SoapUI all goes well and I do receive the 200-response. So the certificates and key in the pfx are valid. Because Basic Authentication in APIM does allow me to connect to the webservice, the cause must be that something goes wrong with sending the client-certificate from API-Management to the webservice.

**Attempt to solve:** I would like to try sending the certificate to the backend using this policy so I can hopefully pass the authentication:

```
<authentication-certificate body="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<byte[]>("byteCertificate"))" password="optional-certificate-password" />
```

**Where I am currently stuck:**
How can I convert my PFX file (containing 4 certificates and a key) to a byte array so that I can use it in API-Management?

Comment: Is the Webservice written in C#?

Comment: No, it is written in Java.

Comment: And the request goes through a SAP load balancer before it reaches the application.

Comment: And the same Webservice should provide the certificate as a byte[] by calling an HTTP request, making it possible to use it in API Management?

Comment: @Spirit: No, API-management calls the webservice. In the past I have been able to disclose other API's through APIM with client certificate authentication, this works fine. But now I have run in a situation where the client-certificate works great when send by SoapUI from my PC, but the webservice responds with a 401-response when APIM tries the same thing. The technical support staff from the webservice tells me that there is a compatibility issue between SAP and Azure caused by the way Azure sends client-certificates.